# How to run Cassandra cluster on Mesos using Marathon Framework?

Tags: json, scala, cassandra, mesos, marathon

I also tried running a simple json application of printing "hi" and its showing the desirable output.

If I can get Cassandra-Cluster json file which I can POST on Marathon Framework?

I tried running this application on Marathon Framework but its showing Delayed status there.

I think there is issue in value of "Volume-driver"

```
{
"id": "cassandra-seed",
"instances": 1,
"cpus": 1,
"mem": 2048,
"env": {
    "CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME": "DemoCluster",
    "CASSANDRA_SEEDS": "54.187.196.55"
},
"container": {
    "type": "DOCKER",
    "docker": {
        "image": "cassandra:3.10",
        "parameters": [
            {
                "key": "volume-driver",
                "value": "pxd"
            },
            {
                "key": "volume",
                "value": "size=2,name=CassandraSeed:/var/lib/cassandra"
            }
        ],
        "portMappings": [
            {
                "containerPort": 7000,
                "hostPort": 0,
                "name": "storage",
                "protocol": "tcp"
            },
            {
                "containerPort": 7001,
                "hostPort": 0,
                "name": "ssl",
                "protocol": "tcp"
            },
            {
                "containerPort": 7199,
                "hostPort": 0,
                "name": "jmx",
                "protocol": "tcp"
            },
            {
                "containerPort": 9042,
                "hostPort": 0,
                "name": "native-client",
                "protocol": "tcp"
            },
            {
                "containerPort": 9160,
                "hostPort": 0,
                "name": "thrift-client",
                "protocol": "tcp"
            }
        ]
    }
}
}
```

Comment: show your code please

Comment: Without using DCOS